# Enforce inheritance in .net

Tags: .net, inheritance

Is it possible to enforce inheritance in .net?

For example, I have a class library project which contains a base class say "BaseEntity". I have 3 classes say "EntityA", "EntityB" and "EntityC" and all these classes inherit from this base class. Now when I create another class in this project, .net should give me a compile time error that this class does not inherit from the class "BaseEntity".

Comment: How would you propose that the compiler know the new class is even *supposed* to inherit from `BaseEntity`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do this (and I think Jon Skeet is right when he says you should not), you could write a helper command line utility which loads the specific assembly, tests your inheritance rules by using reflection. To get a compile time error, call this program within a postbuild event of your project.

Comment: Hi Doc I know it is not correct to do this but the thing is this project will contain only those classes which needs to be inherited with the "BaseEntity" class. Anyways I did as you said and it worked well. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 8):

You can't force the C# compiler to make *every* class within a project inherit from a particular other class, no. Nor should you. What if you want to create some helper class, or other non-entity class? Why should *everything* in the project be an entity?

Now two ways you *can* force inheritance:

- You can make `BaseEntity` an abstract class, so that whenever you deal with an instance of `BaseEntity` you're really dealing with an instance of some derived class.
- You can write a generic type or method using a type parameter with a constraint such that the type argument must be `BaseEntity` or a derived class:

  ```
  public void EntityLoader<T> where T : BaseEntity
  ```

Neither of those are what you're asked for, but they're what's available.

Comment: He could write a unit test that enforces a pattern though, like ensuring all entity classes have the right base class. "enforce" in the sense that it will fail if he breaks the pattern.

Comment: @Lasse: That's true. I'd suggest that he didn't though :)

Comment: It's a very brittle architecture.